# mongodb sharding chunks not working

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I've one collection enable sharding by id key on 2 shard `rs01` and `rs02`

Today I added a new shard `rs03` into cluster.
I've checked balancer status by `sh.status()` as below:

```
shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs01",  "host" : "rs01/mongo30-01:27017,mongo30-02:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "rs02",  "host" : "rs02/mongo30-03:27017,mongo30-04:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "rs03",  "host" : "rs03/mongo30-05:27017,mongo30-06:27017" }
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  yes
```

and some chunks already migrated to `rs03`

```
{  "_id" : "myDB",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs01" }
    myDB.myCo
        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
        chunks:
            rs01    20027
            rs02    19532
            rs03    8
```

I found I set too few memory on `rs03`.
I stopped `mongod` service on `rs03`, added memory and start it after reboot.

After many hours, I found the migrated chunks still `8`.
I checked the operation in `rs03` primary by `db.currentOp()` as below:

```
{
  "inprog": [
    {
      "desc": "migrateThread",
      "threadId": "0x22677e00",
      "opid": 206642,
      "active": true,
      "secs_running": 19754,
      "microsecs_running": NumberLong("19754679731"),
      "op": "none",
      "ns": "myDB.myCo",
      "query": {

      },
      "msg": "step 2 of 6",
      "numYields": 0,
      "locks": {

      },
      "waitingForLock": false,
      "lockStats": {
        "Global": {
          "acquireCount": {
            "r": NumberLong("662"),
            "w": NumberLong("660")
          }
        },
        "Database": {
          "acquireCount": {
            "r": NumberLong("1"),
            "w": NumberLong("659"),
            "W": NumberLong("1")
          }
        },
        "Collection": {
          "acquireCount": {
            "r": NumberLong("1"),
            "w": NumberLong("330"),
            "W": NumberLong("1")
          }
        },
        "oplog": {
          "acquireCount": {
            "w": NumberLong("328")
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

the opid kept as "step 2 of 6" for many hours.
Anything I can do to make the migration going on?
I tried to kill the opid and it forked again still "step 2 of 6" now.
and the chunks in `sh.status()` still `8`.

Comment: Your question may fit better on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), check their [help center](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before you post to make sure.

Comment: cool, I didn't know the dba sister site there. thanks :) I've voted to close here as your suggestion